# MVC HttpGet Edit method Parameters (string userId vs string Id)

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I just spent a couple hours trying to figure out why my Edit action was not catching UserId value when I try to get a single object.

**This did not work**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(string userId)
{            
    var user = _profile.ClubProfiles.First(u => u.UserId == userId);
    var model = new EditUserViewModel();
    model.PhoneNumber = user.MyUser.PhoneNumber;
    model.FirstName = user.FirstName;
    model.LastName = user.LastName;
    model.UserId = user.UserId;

    return View(model);
}
```

**This worked**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(string Id)
{            
    var user = _profile.ClubProfiles.First(u => u.UserId == Id);
    var model = new EditUserViewModel();
    model.PhoneNumber = user.MyUser.PhoneNumber;
    model.FirstName = user.FirstName;
    model.LastName = user.LastName;
    model.UserId = user.UserId;

    return View(model);
}
```

**Why did the second parameter (string Id) work and not the first parameter (string userId)?**

This is the route In my Index View

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.UserId })
```

This is my default route

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: how are you calling the method?

Comment: Can you please post how you have defined your routes?

Comment: Because your default route will be `{controller}/{action}/{id}`. To make the first work, you need a specific route `YourControllerName/Edit/{userid}`

Comment: From your edit, the following will work for the first method `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { userid = item.UserId })` although it will create `/Edit/Edit?userid=1` (rather than `/Edit/Edit/1` unless you create a specific route

Comment: @StephenMuecke Apparently this `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"` is very important to understand. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Komengem - did you not notice the `id = item.UserId`  <-- Note `id`, or the `"{controller}/{action}/{id}",` <-- note the `{id}` or the `id = UrlParameter.Optional` <-- note the `id`, it was literally all over the place...  even in code you, yourself wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should know that in some place in your `Global.asax.cs` file, there is a method called `RegisterRoutes`, which has something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              // Route name 
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

This means that when you call to (for example) the url `yourController/edit/123`, it will search for a controller called `yourController`, a method called `edit` with `id` as a parameter. This is by default, of course you can change it and do whatever you need with these routes.

But, as you see, this is searching for `id`, and not for `userId`, I think that this is your explanation, let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: I am using a default route, see updated post. I am also aware of how routes work, my interest is understanding the difference in the parameters passed to the Edit method

Comment: `{id}` means that it expect for a parameter with that name, any else you pass will be expected as `?some=else&you=need`

Comment: Makes sense, now i know more. Although i feel like they should upgrade the technology so that it picks up anything passed as parameter as id

Comment: if you want to check for a tutorial, [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) should be ok for you